# Tkinter program runs button command on startup?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, openfiledialog

So I have a program that is basically supposed to have a button that opens a file dialog in the (username) folder. But when I run the program it opens without even pushing the button. What's more, the button doesn't even show up. So in addition to that problem I have to find a way to turn the selected directory into a string.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
import getpass
gui = tkinter.Tk()
user = getpass.getuser()
tkinter.Button(gui, command=tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/Users/%s' % user)).pack()
gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first issue, you need to put the call to `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename` in a function so that it isn't run on startup.  I actually just answered a question about this this morning, so you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722432/sending-a-variable-with-a-button-command-python-3-3-tkinter/20722476#20722476) for the answer.

Regarding your second issue, the button isn't showing up because you never placed it on the window.  You can use the [`grid`](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) method for this:

```
button = tkinter.Button(gui, command=lambda: tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/Users/%s' % user))
button.grid()
```

All in all, your code should be like this:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
import getpass
gui = tkinter.Tk()
user = getpass.getuser()
button = tkinter.Button(gui, command=lambda: tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/Users/%s' % user))
button.grid()
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! So now for the second part of the question: how would I go about making the directory into a string value?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use a geometry manager on the button:

```
button = tkinter.Button(window, command=test)
button.pack()
```

If you don't do it, the button won't be drawn. You might find this link useful: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm.
Note that to pass the command to handler you have to write only the name of the function (Like it's descibed in the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I just wanted to add an alternate method of preventing Tkinter from running methods at start-up. You can use Python's `functools.partial` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)):

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
import getpass
import functools

gui = tkinter.Tk()
user = getpass.getuser()
button = tkinter.Button(
  gui, 
  command=functools.partial(
    tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename, 
    initialdir='C:/Users/%s' % user)
  )
button.grid()
gui.mainloop()
```